# How do you confirm a default input for an action in bixby?

Tags: bixby

I would like to collect an address input for an action "evaluate". Ideally the behavior would be something like this:

```
1) Evaluate is initiated
2) a default address is pulled from user profile,
user is asked if they would like to use this address
3) if no default address or user does not want to use it, 
prompt user for an address
4) Evaluate action runs with either default address or custom input address
```

What I am thinking of doing is adding 2 constructor actions that could potentially return a geo.Address object, ReturnSelfAddress and GetCustomAddress. ReturnSelfAddress will collect an address from the self library capsule and GetCustomAddress will prompt the user to enter an address as a geo.UnstructuredAddress and convert that into a regular geo.Address.

The input to the Evaluate action is this:

```
input (address) {
      type (geo.Address)
      min (Required)
      max (One)
      default-init {
        intent {
          goal: ReturnSelfAddress
        }
      }
    }
```

Then I would have a confirmation view that would confirm ReturnSelfAddress to let the user select that if desired. If ReturnSelfAddress fails, then Evaluate will still look for a geo.Address input. I would have an input-view that would match the geo.Address concept and prompt the user to input a geo.UnstructuredAddress. Something like this (not sure if this is 100% correct):

```
input-view {
  match: geo.Address(this)
  message ("What is your street address?")
  render{
    form {
      elements {
        text-input {
          id (address)
          label("Address")
          required (true)
          type (geo.UnstructuredAddress)
        }
      }
      on-submit {
        goal: GetCustomAddress
        value: viv.core.FormElement(address)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if the user rejects the default, then I will have an on-abort goal of GetCustomAddress that would prompt the user:

```
on-abort {
            intent {
            goal: GetCustomAddress
            }
        }
```

This seems to be very involved, and I am questioning if there is a feature that i might be missing that will help me get the desired behavior. So i guess i have 2 questions:

1) Before i go too deep down this rabbit hole, will this idea work?

2) Is there a better way to get the desired behavior of "try for default and if none or user rejects, prompt for input"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the confirmation view, but here is an easier way you might find useful.

1. Define the input in action model with **default-init** and **prompt-behavior (AlwaysElicitation)**

```
    input (email) {
      type (TypeTextEmail)
      min (Required) max (One)
      default-init {
        intent {
          goal: FetchEmailFromName
          value: $expr(name)
        }
      }
      prompt-behavior (AlwaysElicitation)
    }
```

2. Define input view to overwrite the default if user want to

```
input-view {
  match: TypeTextEmail(this)
  render {
    form {
      elements {
        text-input {
          id (this)
          type (TypeTextEmail)
          label ("Email:")
          max-length (50)
          value ("#{value(this)}")
        }
      }
      on-submit {
        goal: TypeTextEmail
        value: viv.core.FormElement(this)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3. You can download and try the training example in [example.inputview](https://github.com/MinChengVivLabs/example.inputview)
4. For confirmation view, please refer the [example.shirt](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-sample-shirt) on Github

Comment: That's so much simpler than what i was doing, thank you for all the headaches i will not have to deal with!